# Improving this prime number listing implementation

Tags: python, math

This following code lists all prime number.

Is this a new implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

How can the code be improved to run faster as it gets to higher numbers?

```
def PrimeSieve(curNum):
    prime = True
    del updateList[:]
    for cp in PrimeList:
        daPrime, daSkip = cp
        if curNum == daSkip:
            prime = False
            upcp = (daPrime, daSkip + daPrime)
            updateList.append(upcp)
        else:
            updateList.append(cp)
    if prime:
        updateList.append((curNum,2*curNum))
    return prime

PrimeList = []
updateList = []

for x in range(2, 1111):
    print(x, PrimeSieve(x))
    del PrimeList[:]
    for i in updateList:
        PrimeList.append(i)
```

Comment: Maybe this should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are probably many ways to improve this but one that strikes me most is - why do you have updateList and PrimeList, you keep deleting and copying them over at each iteration. This takes more time as the lists get longer. Getting rid of one of them would be my first change.

```
def PrimeSieve(curNum):
    prime = True
    addSet = set()
    delSet = set()
    for cp in PrimeSet:
        daPrime, daSkip = cp
        if curNum == daSkip:
            prime = False
            addSet.add((daPrime, daSkip + daPrime))
            delSet.add(cp)
    if prime:
        addSet.add((curNum, 2 * curNum))
    PrimeSet.difference_update(delSet)
    PrimeSet.update(addSet)
    return prime


PrimeSet = set()

for x in range(2, 11111):
    print(x, PrimeSieve(x))
```

(Edit: replace list with set for efficient replace)

Comment: Good idea - easy to read code. But the list will then grow with extraneous items. You don't want to PrimeList.append(upcp) without deleting cp at some point.

Comment: you can always only keep track of elements you want to add and remove in each iteration and update the PrimeList before returning from the function. Removing object by value works better on set than list, as you don't need the list to be in any particular order

Comment: I kept your original formatting but you should rather follow python standards. Variable names in python don't use CamelCase. you should use snake_case for everything except class names (prime_sieve, da_prime, cur_num), and more meaningful names (I don't know what daPrime and daSkip mean). read more about python coding standard (called PEP8) here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thanks so much! I wanted to go pro with python but now I am a hobbyist so not too worried about names. But b4 posting again I will review this!